# Click event for div with two floated elements on IE6

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I have a `<div>` with two floated elements inside of it. I'm using jQuery to attach a click event handler to this `<div>`. The handler only gets called when I click one of the two floated elements. The empty space inside of the `<div>` does not work.

Here's what the markup looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Some lovely header text here</h4>
  <img src="images/plus.png"/>
  <div style="clear: both;"/>
</div>
```

Here's my Javascript (I'm using some other events, too):

```
// Expand scenarios when clicked on
scenario_header.live("click", function() { 
  $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
  $("+ div", this).slideToggle();
});

// Toggle hover class when hovering
scenario_header.live("mouseover", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
scenario_header.live("mouseout", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

This works perfectly in Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: The CSS is a little messy (I'm using a lot of classes). Ionut G. Stan already solved my problem below, but not all of his CSS is necessary (in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to apply some additional CSS so that the wrapper `DIV` really wraps its children. Something like this should be enough:

```
div {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block; /* weird stuff, but it's needed for IE6 */
}
div {
 display: block; /* needed to reset display for non IE6 browsers */
}
```

Comment: Cool, although only setting `display: inline-block;` was enough. I'll accept your answer if you fix it (I don't feel right accepting it if it's a little wrong). Up-vote in either case :)

Comment: Awww. Now I get it. Without setting `display` back to `block` it no longer looks right in Firefox. Thanks Ionut!

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I modified the second comment. Indeed, it's needed for FF.